# Can Atomic values change during an "&&" operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic, interleave

I am aware of the next scenario: (Weird formatting, I know)

```
private final AtomicBoolean aBoolean = new AtomicBoolean(true);

public void doSomething() {
    if (
        aBoolean.get()                       // line A
            &&                               // line B
        aBoolean.compareAndSet(true, false)  // line C
        ) {
        System.out.println("Was true!")
    }
}
```

If thread #1 and thread #2 enter `doSomething()` at exactly the same time this will happen:

1. Thread #1 and thread #2 will read `aBoolean.get()` as being ==
   "true" simultaneously.
2. Both will execute the "&&" operator.
3. CMPXCHG instruction kicks in for both threads simultaneously:

   3.1 LOCK prefix is used natively

   3.2 Either thread #1 or #2 arrives first, winning the race.

   3.3 Winning thread compares (is aBoolean == true ?) this will return "true", hence aBoolean will be set to "false".

   3.4 aBoolean is now false.

   3.5 Losing thread compares (is aBoolean == true ?) this will return "false", hence short-circuiting any further operations.
4. winning thread will print "Was true!".

**Under the perspective of the "losing" thread the first `aBoolean.get()` in "line A" was .... let's say... a "lie".**

Now under the assumption that executions can happen in between operators, as it just did in the example above, let's add a second method for a second scenario:

```
public void unluckySet() {
    aBoolean.set(false);
}
```

Let's say Thread #3 just so happens to arrive and execute `unluckySet()` at precisely the exact moment that our "winning thread" arrived at "line B" where the "&&" is executing.

If winning thread went as far as to reach "line B" it means it reached "line A" with aBoolean being "true".

**My questions are:**

Will CMPXCHG read the updated value correctly as being "false"?, meaning the `.set()` is also held by the same lock as the `compareAndSet()`.

In concurrency and between threads:

Do operators ("&&", "||", "==", "=", maybe even "return;"??) happen at any nano second, OR are they interleaved with executions (";") so that both END in an interleaved manner, preventing possible collisions?

Comment: yes they can. Atomic values are only atomic within a single operation. `atomicOp1() && atomicOp2()` are 2 separate atomic operations

Comment: Note that `AtomicBoolean` are nothing special, the jvm does not treat them special in any way and therefore two separate interactions with them are just that: separate.

Comment: Thanks @Felix I am looking at some code right now [JCTools Java Concurrency Tools for the JVM. ](https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools/blob/master/jctools-core/src/main/java/org/jctools/maps/NonBlockingHashMap.java), and I see there is simply too much happening between line 666 start of a spin lock for "CAS_key(" and line 775 "CAS_val(" which is not even in a spin lock, I guess that is not entirely thread safe... correct? That code has been forked 444 times and 2.9k stars rating.

Comment: ...correction, there is a spin lock, but in the form a self-referential method... which is still not entirely safe since things can change even between operators...

Comment: "Too much" is irrelevant; if the two operations are **not the same** then the code has to be prepared for other stuff to happen between them.  I don't care if there's a thousand lines of code separating them, or none at all.  But at a glance I don't see a problem.  Note that `V` was loaded before the key slot was claimed.  If another thread changed the value before the `CAS_val` occurred, then the CAS will fail and the code appears to handle that case.

Comment: Well, lines like `int dummy = DUMMY_VOLATILE;` indicate that this code is designed to happen to work under specific implementations, at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java memory model is *sequential consistency* in the absence of data races (which your program doesn't have).  This is very strong; it says that all reads and writes in your program form a total order, which is consistent with program order.  So you can imagine that reads and writes from different threads simply get interleaved, or shuffled together, in some fashion - without changing the relative ordering of actions made from the same thread as each other.

But for this purpose, every action is a separate element in this order.
So just by the mere fact that `aBoolean.get()` and `aBoolean.compareAndSet()` are **two** actions and not **one** action, it is possible for any number of other actions by other threads to take place in between them.

It doesn't matter whether those actions are part of a single statement, or different statements; or what kind of expression they appear in; or what operators (if any) are between them; or what computations the thread itself may or may not be doing around them.  There is no way in which two actions can be "so close together" that nothing else can happen in between, short of replacing them by a single action defined to be atomic by the language.

---

At the level of the machine, a very simple way this can happen is that, since `aBoolean.get()` and `aBoolean.compareAndSet()` are almost certainly two different machine instructions, an interrupt may arrive in between them.  This interrupt could cause the thread to be delayed for any amount of time, during which other threads could do anything they wish.  So it is entirely possible that threads #1 and #2 are both interrupted in between their `get()` and `compareAndSet()`, and that thread #3 executes its `set` in the meantime.

Caution: Reasoning about how a particular machine might work is often useful for understanding why undesired behavior is possible, as in the previous paragraph.  But it is not a substitute for reasoning about the formal memory model, and should not be used to try to argue that a program *must* have its desired behavior.  Even if a particular machine you have in mind would do the right thing for your code, or you can't think of a way in which a plausible machine would fail, that does not prove that your program is correct.

So trying to say "oh, the machine will do a `lock cmpxchg` and so blah blah blah and everything works" isn't wise; some other machine you haven't thought of might work in a totally different fashion, that still complies with the abstract Java memory model but otherwise violates your x86-based expectations.  In fact, x86 is a particularly poor example for this: for historical reasons, it provides a rather strong set of instruction-level memory ordering guarantees that many other "weakly ordered" architectures do not, and so there may be many things that Java abstractly allows but that x86 in practice won't do.

Comment: Note that nothing in the specification says that `compareAndSet` gets compiled to `lock cmpxchg`, so even when running under x86, you can’t use the behavior of this instruction to reason what *Java* will do. The JIT compiler & optimizer is free to do whatever it wants, as long as it obeys the JMM. But in the specific case of `aBoolean.get() && aBoolean.compareAndSet(true, false)`, it doesn’t really matter, as the result is either `true` or `false` and it makes no observable difference whether `aBoolean` was changed to `false` in-between or was already `false` before.